# How to effectively retrieve two friends of each person in neo4j

Tags: nosql, neo4j, cypher

For example, I have a neo4j graph like this:

```
n1 -> n1
n1 -> n2
n1 -> n3
n2 -> n4
n2 -> n5
n3 -> n6
```

The expected results are:

```
n1 -> n1
n1 -> n2
n2 -> n4
n2 -> n5
n3 -> n6
```

Either Cypher query or REST API will be OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little ugly in the current version (2.0.0-M01).

```
match a:Person-->b:Person 
return a, head(collect(b)), head(tail(collect(b)))
```

Soon you'll be able to do ranges and this could be

```
match a:Person-->b:Person 
return a, collect(b)[0..1]
```

See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/neo4j/subset/neo4j/nnihjVqMHbQ/PVbCe_3z85oJ

and for an actual working copy of it:

https://github.com/mneedham/neo4j/commits/